# How to write message to current user by Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

[Have read documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) about firebase implementation, but didn't find anything about how to send message to current user.

I have carried out implementation, but issue is when i send message all users who have connected to my firebase have ability to see this current message.

I have to make implementation in order to send message to one current user.

I don't understand how to make it. If someone have already made such implementation give me advice.

**EDIT**

It is standard snippet of code to send a message

```
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ChatMessage friendlyMessage = new
                    ChatMessage(mMsgEditText.getText().toString(),
                    mUsername,
                    mPhotoUrl);
            mSimpleFirechatDatabaseReference.child("messages")
                    .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            mMsgEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
```

And it is standard snippet of code to fecth data if it were refreshed on firebase DB

```
@Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirechatMsgViewHolder viewHolder, ChatMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            viewHolder.msgTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            viewHolder.userTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.userImageView.setImageDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
            } else {
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.userImageView);
            }
        }
```

Anyway question is which way i can understand that current message belong to one or another user?

Because as far as i understand all users connect to the same firebase DB

even if i will assign id to users anyway each exist device will get all refreshed DB and then checked which of messages direct to him and which doesn't.

I want to carry out this check on server side. Server should decide which messages belong to one or another users. it is the issue

Comment: It sounds like you've already tried something and are having problems getting it to work. In that case, add the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question (read the link for what a so-called MCVE is and why this is helpful).

Comment: I noticed that you're referring to the documentation on firebase.com, which comes with a warning at the top that it is no longer updated. I highly recommend that you switch over to the new Firebase documentation. The corresponding page can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen was added

Comment: To detect whether a message is from the current user or someone else, you will need to sign in those users. For example with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). After that, you can record the `uid` for each message and detect whether it's their own message based on that.  I noticed that your code that writes a message ignores potential errors, so recommend that you [add an error listener](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database#t=20160830144148241419).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok, what do you think about such consept, is it correct? When one user send message to another, the first `json` is creating with a `body` `title` `id recipent` and so on... this `json` is sending to server side, next server with help of Firebase API send notification to current user by `id recipent` and with `name of subcribing chanel` and recipent will use this name to retrive all masseges from firebase DB (it is excactly conversation storege) ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen could you please explain more? I re-read your answer and question is - you mean that i should attached ID to each message? And then check entire list of messages from DB to pick my own?